# Passing PHP id to a jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this jQuery in my header:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h5").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

and I am  fetching data from database. When I clicks on h5 it shows and hides all the paragraphs. I want to show and hide a particular paragraph when I click on h5. This is my PHP:

```php
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
    echo "<div style='background-color: #F1F0FF; pading:35px'>";echo"<h5 id=".$results['id'].">".$results['question']."</h5>";echo "<p id=".$results['id']."><span>option A:</span>" .$results['option_a']."<span> <br>option B:</span>".$results['option_b']."<span><br/>option C:</span>".$results['option_c'].
    "<span><br>option D:</span>".$results['option_d']."<span><br>option E:</span>".$results['option_e']."<span><br>Correct Ans:</span>".$results['correct_ans']. 
    "<span><br>FMGE Year:</span>".$results['fmge_year']."<span><br>FMGE Month :</span>".$results['fmge_month']."<span><br>Contributor:</span>".$results['contributor']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: You cannot have the same ID multiple times in a page, ID's have to be unique. In your case you can use classes and use that to address the paragraph or - if you know the paragraph is always the next element after the heading - you can use jQuery's `next()` like `$(this).next()`. Adn personally I would use a `ul` or `dl` instead of all these spans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery `.siblings()` to select the matching paragraph:

```
$(this).siblings('p').slideToggle(); //<- slideToggle is just for example
```

Comment: I am new to J Query can please post what i have to write inside script and any changes required to PHP part

Answer (score 0):

Like  @jeroen said, but different- just require

in  
css: !writing style in php can be headache

```
div.content {
    background-color: #F1F0FF; 
    pading:35px
}
```

Html format

```
<div class="content">
  <h5>...</h5>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".content").on("click", "h5", function() {
     $(this).parent()
          .children('p')
          .slideToggle();
});
```

And there is still other way.